# LightGBM: train() vs update() vs refit()

Tags: python, machine-learning, lightgbm

I'm implementing *[LightGBM](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)* (Python) into a **continuous learning** pipeline. My goal is to train an initial model and update the model (e.g. every day) with newly available data.
Most examples load an already trained model and apply train() once again:

```
updated_model = lightgbm.train(params=last_model_params, train_set=new_data, init_model = last_model)
```

However, I'm wondering if this is actually the correct way to approach continuous learning within the *LightGBM* library since the amount of fitted trees (`num_trees()`) grows for every application of `train()` by `n_estimators`. For my understanding a model update should take an initial *model definition* (under a given set of *model parameters*) and refine it without ever growing the amount of trees/size of the model definition.

I find the documentation regarding [`train()`](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.Booster.html#lightgbm.Booster.update), [`update()`](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.Booster.html#lightgbm.Booster.update) and [`refit()`](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.Booster.html#lightgbm.Booster.refit) not particularly helpful. **What would be considered the right approach to implement continuous learning with LightGBM?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In `lightgbm` (the Python package for LightGBM), these entrypoints you've mentioned do have different purposes.

The main `lightgbm` model object is a `Booster`. A fitted `Booster` is produced by training on input data. Given an initial trained `Booster`...

- `Booster.refit()` does not change the structure of an already-trained model. It just updates the leaf counts and leaf values based on the new data. **It will not add any trees to the model**.
- `Booster.update()` will perform exactly 1 additional round of gradient boosting on an existing `Booster`. **It will add at most 1 tree to the model.**
- `train()` with an `init_model` will perform gradient boosting for `num_iterations` additional rounds. It also allows for lots of other functionality, like custom callbacks (e.g. to change the learning rate from iteration-to-iteration) and early stopping (to stop adding trees if performance on a validation set fails to improve). **It will add up to `num_iterations` trees to the model.**

> What would be considered the right approach to implement continuous learning with LightGBM?

There are trade-offs involved in this choice and no one of these is the globally "right" way to achieve the goal "modify an existing model based on newly-arrived data".

`Booster.refit()` is the only one of these approaches that meets your definition of *"refine [the model] without ever growing the amount of trees/size of the model definition"*. But it could lead to drastic changes in the predictions produced by the model, especially if the batch of newly-arrived data is much smaller than the original training data, or if the distribution of the target is very different.

`Booster.update()` is the simplest interface for this, but a single iteration might not be enough to get most of the information from the newly-arrived data into the model. For example, if you're using fairly shallow trees (say, `num_leaves=7`) and a very small learning rate, even newly-arrived data that is very different from the original training data might not change the model's predictions by much.

`train(init_model=previous_model)` is the most flexible and powerful option, but it also introduces more parameters and choices. If you choose to use `train(init_model=previous_model)`, pay attention to parameters `num_iterations` and `learning_rate`. Lower values of these parameters will decrease the impact of newly-arrived data on the trained model, higher values will allow a larger change to the model. Finding the right balance between those is a concern for your evaluation framework.