# Update LGBM model in python

Tags: python, updates, lightgbm

I have a LGBM model and want to update it with new data, but the documentation is not helping me a lot.
I have this:

```
from lightgbm import LGBMRegressor
reg = LGBMRegressor(deterministic=True, monotone_constraints=[1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], num_leaves=100, objective='rmse', seed=123)
reg.fit(X_old, y_old)
```

I want something like:

```
reg2 = LGBMRegressor.update(X_new, y_new, init_model = reg)
```

Answer (score 0):

To perform continued training with the `scikit-learn` interface from `lightgbm`, pass a model via keyword argument `init_model` to `LGBMRegressor.fit()`.

As the documentation for `LGBMRegressor.fit()` ([docs link](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.LGBMRegressor.html#lightgbm.LGBMRegressor.fit)) says:

> **init_model**: *(str, pathlib.Path, Booster, LGBMModel or None, optional (default=None)) – Filename of LightGBM model, Booster instance or LGBMModel instance used for continue training.*

Try this example with `lightgbm >= 4.0.0` and `scikit-learn >= 1.3.0`.

```py
import lightgbm as lgb
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression

X, y = make_regression(n_samples=10_000)

# fit initial model for 10 boosting rounds
reg = lgb.LGBMRegressor(n_estimators=10)
reg.fit(X, y)

# confirm that 10 boosting rounds were performed
assert reg.n_iter_ == 10

# fit for 3 more rounds
reg2 = lgb.LGBMRegressor(n_estimators=3)
reg2.fit(X, y, init_model=reg)

# confirm that the new model object contains 13 rounds worth of trees
assert reg2.n_iter_ == 13

# ... and that the original model object is unchanged
assert reg.n_iter_ == 10
```

If you instead want to use the `Booster` object in `lightgbm`, see [LightGBM: train() vs update() vs refit() (answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73669068/3986677).